# Error in restoreInput: argument "value" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a simple shiny UI that accepts input and appends them as a row to one of two tables based on a "TYPE".
However, I am getting the following error.

"Error in restoreInput(id = inputId, default = value): argument "value" is missing, with no default"

I am very new to shiny and am struggling to understand which input may be throwing the error and where I should add "restoreInput()" to fix it.
My script is as follows...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Maintenance/Supply Request:"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Ticket", 
                 selectInput(inputId = "Type", label = "Type", c("Maintenance","Supply")),
                 textInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Name",value = " "),
                 textInput(inputId = "Department", label = "Department", value = " "),
                 dateInput(inputId = "Date", label = "Date", format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),
                 numericInput(inputId = "Urgency", label = "Urgency", min = 1, max = 5),
                 textInput(inputId = "Request", label = "Request", value = " "),
                 actionButton(inputId = "Submit", label = "Submit Ticket")
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Maintenance", tableOutput("Maintenance")),
        tabPanel("Supply", tableOutput("Supply"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  if ( (input$Type = "Maintenance")){
    Maintenance <- reactiveValues()
    Maintenance$df <- data.frame(Name = character(),
                                 Department = character(),
                                 Date = character(),
                                 Urgency = integer(),
                                 Request = character())
    observeEvent(input$Submit, {
      new_row <- data.frame(Name = input$Name,
                            Department = input$Department,
                            Date = input$Date,
                            Urgency = input$Urgency,
                            Request = input$Request)
      Maintenance$df <- rbind(Maintenance$df, new_row)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(Maintenance$df)
  } else {
    Supply <- reactiveValues()
    Supply$df <- data.frame(Name = character(),
                                 Department = character(),
                                 Date = character(),
                                 Urgency = integer(),
                                 Request = character())
    observeEvent(input$Submit, {
      new_row <- data.frame(Name = input$Name,
                            Department = input$Department,
                            Date = input$Date,
                            Urgency = input$Urgency,
                            Request = input$Request)
      Supply$df <- rbind(Supply$df, new_row)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(Supply$df)
  }  
           
 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue which gives rise to the error is the missing `value` for the `numericInput`. However, even after fixing that your app will not work as doing `if ( (input$Type = "Maintenance"))` (where of course `=` should be `==`) will not work as you are trying to access the value of an input outside of a reactive context.

Overall you could simplify your app and make it work like so:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Maintenance/Supply Request:"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      "Ticket",
      selectInput(inputId = "Type", label = "Type", choices = c("Maintenance", "Supply")),
      textInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Name", value = " "),
      textInput(inputId = "Department", label = "Department", value = " "),
      dateInput(inputId = "Date", label = "Date", format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),
      numericInput(inputId = "Urgency", value = 1, label = "Urgency", min = 1, max = 5),
      textInput(inputId = "Request", label = "Request", value = " "),
      actionButton(inputId = "Submit", label = "Submit Ticket")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Maintenance", tableOutput("Maintenance_table")),
        tabPanel("Supply", tableOutput("Supply_table"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactiveValues()
  
  dat$Maintenance <- dat$Supply <- data.frame(
    Name = character(),
    Department = character(),
    Date = character(),
    Urgency = integer(),
    Request = character()
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    new_row <- data.frame(
      Name = input$Name,
      Department = input$Department,
      Date = input$Date,
      Urgency = input$Urgency,
      Request = input$Request
    )
    if (input$Type == "Maintenance") {
      dat$Maintenance <- rbind(dat$Maintenance, new_row)
    } else {
      dat$Supply <- rbind(dat$Supply, new_row)
    }
  })
  
  output$Maintenance_table <- renderTable(dat$Maintenance)
  output$Supply_table <- renderTable(dat$Supply)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8759
```

[image]

Comment: I did figure out that "numericInput()" was missing the value and was working to fix the modifying of the reactive value, thank you very much i had not thought to use a Dat repository instead.